# Firebug debug jumps/breaks on non-existing breakpoint!

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

So I have this page with a bunch of jQuery functions.
I have no breakpoints at all but Firebug always breaks/jumps to a JS function like there is a breakpoint but there isn't!!!

[image]

Its also breaks some JS in the page (not everything). I mean, I hit 'play' or 'F8' a couple of times to continue/stop debugging but then some JS functions does not work anymore.
Everything works fine when Firebug is turned off.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.13 with Firebug 1.6.2.

Any idea why its happening and how to fix it??

Comment: This start happen to me when I upgraded to firebug version 1.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to uninstall firefox and firebug and the reinstall from scratch.

Comment: I was using the Firefox built in debugger and experiencing the same problem.  A clean installation was exactly what fixed the issue for me

Comment: Yeah sure, every time this happens (which is 50% times I use breakpoints).

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me (on FireFox v18.0.1 w/ FireBug v1.11.1) was to reset all FireBug options: FireBug menu -> Options -> Reset All Firebug Options. I didn't figure out which exact option was causing the problem.

Comment: Does not work in any 2020/21 versions :/ The Guest answer below does however

Answer (score 5):

I've ran into this issue where I run into a breakpoint and it doesn't even show up in the breakpoints tab.

One thing I've found that works is to create an actual breakpoint on the line where firebug is breaking, and then manually disable it with the checkbox on the breakpoints tab.

In my experience this has stopped firebug from randomly breaking on those lines.

Comment: Thanx, thats the only thing that helps me!!

Comment: 8 years later and this is either still or once again the right answer

Answer (score 3):

Solved!
In My case, I clicked in the button showed bellow.
Just click it again :)

Note: my print screen is in portuguese, but it's not a problem to understand.

[image: firebug]

Answer (score 3):

Probably a little late answer but you probably added a breakpoint in an error and there is no error anymore so you can't disable it normally.

This is what you have to do:

1. Go to Script Tab
2. Click the breakpoints tab in the right side
3. Remove the breakpoints that you want by clicking the small x

Here's an image to illustrate:

[image: Firebug invisible breakpoints]

Comment: Helped me, but not exactly as described. Had do add breakpoint at this place and remove by means on menu on the right. Other solutions didn't help me.

Comment: PS: please note that buggy firebug would tremendously slowdown performance of code that has such disabled breakpoints...

Comment: i had this same problem in chromium.  I had created a breakpoint by clicking on a line of code and i had not realizrd it

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but same thing just started happening to me.

In the Debugger on the right under 'Breakpoints' it said 'No breakpoints', but as the page loaded it kept breaking at a particular line, and the page wouldn't finish without me manually stepping through a load of stuff.

If I then added a breakpoint on that line (as suggested above) it added it to the list of breakpoints on the right as expected, but weirdly a second breakpoint (for a different line) magically appeared in the list of breakpoints as well, which seemed a bit buggy. Removing either/both didn't stop the problem.

On closer inspection of my code I realised I'd messed up commenting around that line (using a clumsy mix of /**/ and //) and that was causing the debugger to kick-in and break execution. I haven't seen mistakes in code do this before - I normally just get an error in the console, but the page finishes. Maybe something about errors in comment tags triggers the debugger?

Anyway, thought I'd share in case it's useful for someone else.