# firebug keeps stopping execution of script

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I must have clicked something accidently in Firebug, because on my site it keeps stopping execution w/ a little yellow arrow in the margin in the script console.

I cannot seem to stop this from happening, and nobody else on my team has this problem with firefox on the same page.

Is there a way to reset the debugger?

Screenshot: http://chovy.dyndns.org/test/bug.png

Comment: What error message is it printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the browser toolbar on the Firebug button open the menu and select the last option "Empty the activation list".

Answer (score 2):

In the Script tab, clear all Breakpoints (which should be listed in a tab on the right).

Comment: the breakpoints tab is empty, yet I'm still seeing a yellow arrow.

Comment: is it halted on a `throw` statement? does it still happen if you restart firefox?

Comment: yes, keeps happening. I ended up building a new profile and that got rid of the problem. I think it is a bug w/ firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `about:config` in the URL bar, and make sure that `extensions.firebug.breakOnErrors` preference is set to false to *not* break on an error.

Answer (score 0):

In the Script tab, click arrow pointing down. and deselect last two options.

Comment: I still get a yellow arrow. and execution still stops.

Comment: is there any exception in console?

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002139/firebug-debug-jumps-breaks-on-non-existing-breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve this problem. Even by removing breakpoints.json in the Firefox profile firebug folder it just re-appeared. I had to create a brand new profile and re-install all my plugins. That fixed the problem.

On mac, you can execute this to bring up profile manager:

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Answer (score 0):

If you Deactivate Firebug (Tools->Webdeveloper->Firebug->Deactivate Firebug) the problem goes away for as long as you keep Firebug closed.
Removing and reinstalling Firebug solves it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You could just deactivate the script tab versus the entire firebug tool.

Bring up firebug, navigate to the script tab, click the down arrow unclick the "Enabled" option. Then just do the same thing again but enable it this time.

Had a similar issue, was pretty annoying but this solved it.